# WTForms заполнение формы из dict

Tags: python, flask

Нарисовал тестовую формочку:

```
class TestForm(Form):
name = StringField(u'Ваше имя')
categories = SelectMultipleField(u'Категория', choices=[
    ('f', 'First'),
    ('s', 'Second'),
    ('th', 'Third')], validators=[DataRequired()])
gender = BooleanField(u'Вы мужчина?')
ostype = RadioField(u'Ваша операционка', choices=[
    ('l', 'Linux'),
    ('x', 'OS X'),
    ('w', 'Windows'),
])
```

Данные для редактирования прилетают в JSON. Заполнить форму у меня получилось только так:

```
    raw_data = {
    'name': u'Ваничка',
    'categories': [u'f', u'th'],
    'gender': True,
    'ostype': u'w',
}

if id is not None:
    rdk = raw_data.keys()
    FormDat = namedtuple('FormDat', rdk)
    formobj = FormDat._make([raw_data[key] for key in rdk])
    form = TestForm(obj=formobj)
```

Работает, но как-то слишком оно уродливо. Есть какие другие варианты?